# Facebook can't get the right image size from blog

Tags: facebook, image, thumbnails, blogger

A friend needs help with a blog, the problem is that when he posts something from blog to facebook he can't get the right thumbnail, the problem is that at facebook debugger the image that it gets is the thumbnail of the picture. The blog is on blogger and has been used a plugin for the share buttons(I don't know which plugin). Sorry that i don't post some code to help you better, but I'm just searching in dark to find a solution.

**EDIT**

I added these but again i have the problem with the picture, fb debugger says its too small. The `data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl` is responsible for the size (72x72 generates). Is there a way to change this?

```
xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns# at the end of the html tag

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/487911_488950037808372_1165794149_n.jpg' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Does the blog implement the appropriate [`og:meta` tags?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#blog)

Comment: as i've seen no, but how i add them at prototype and set em get the post image for every post? i have basic knowledge in html,css,php, from my university but this is a little bit confusing as i haven't created the blog and never worked with a blog again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: After adding the appropriate `og:meta` tags everything seems to work better, the problem still exists(og:image too small for fb debugger) but now i have the choice of the post picture. Thanks very much Lix, the community and the guides i found around the net(I'll post them).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a higher resolution image by using the tag - `data:blog.postImageUrl` instead of `data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl`

But as of late 2016, Blogger automatically adds the `og:image` tag (as well as `og:url` , `og:title` and `og:description`) via the `<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>` which is present in the Blogger template. Also the image resolution is on much higher side (Set to 1200x630 px, to match with the guidelines laid down in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images )